# Where to find SharePoint Tips and Tricks?

Tags: sharepoint

Where to find SharePoint Tips and Tricks?

I want Tips and Tricks not for the Developers but for our customers.

I search and find tips and tricks for developers but I am overlooking or not finding the ones for our customers.

What keywords could I use to find this kind of information?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EndUserSharePoint.com is a good resource for end users / customers - https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/default.aspx